# geth - admin,addPeer() and static-nodes.json don't work

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mining

I'm trying to connect two nodes (both miners) on my private network.

They are based on the same VM in different data directories. They have different ports and are based on the same genesis file and network ID.

The problem is I can't get them to sync and I think the reason is they still can't find each other.

I have tried to use both `admin.addPeer()` inside a console or using `static-nodes.json`, but when I checked with `admin.peers` it still came back with an empty array.

Did anybody else have this problem before?

Comment: If you set the flag '--verbosity 5' when starting geth, you see should more detailed explanations in the logs of why the peers can't connect. Could you supply that information?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it takes a while for the node to start syncing.  You want to make sure the IP and port is actually reachable from the other computer by doing `telnet [ip] [port]`.